# jsp: including a tag twice with an optional parameter

Tags: jsp, attributes, tags, scope

edit: While narrowing down the code after developerwjk's comment, I found that the problem is something else. The problem is that the following results in something being printed to the screen, where I expect nothing on the screen there.

```
<c:if test="${false}">
    <c:out><span class="seperator">|</span></c:out>
</c:if>
```

old text:
We have a tag in jsp with an optional attribute. When the tag is first included with the optional attribute set, it has the expected value. When I include the tag again on the same page without the optional attribute, the attribute still has the value from the previous include, but I want it to be empty. Is there a way to solve this without setting the attribute on the second include to be empty?

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Show at least your includes.

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145622/cif-test-is-always-true